# C# Serialized XML not showing properly in Excel

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I am currently serializing a `List<SomeObject>` to an XML file, which works fine...

In the `SomeObject` properties, one of them is a string that contains multiple items delimited by the `Environment.NewLine` character.

When i open the XML file using Excel, some of the cells containing that property, with a few items in them, show up fine (WrapText is set) and yet some others with more items just show up as a string of # signs.

Is there a way to properly show the property's contents with the new lines in there so that Excel displays them correctly, while retaining the original XML? I mean, is this a Serialization issue, or a display setting in Excel i've missed?

Comment: Pound signs mean that the cell isn't big enough to hold the contents. Make the cell bigger horizontally or, since you have it wrapping text, vertically.

Comment: i tried... it won't change the display. For example, there are 6 lines in one cell, i made the cell take up the entire screen (horizontally and vertically)... it still shows pound signs...

Comment: How many pound signs? I assume they don't fill the cell, then?

Comment: In any event, you should look at the XML you're outputting and see whether that's what you expect it to be, then find some documentation on how Excel reads XML documents, and see if those match up.

Comment: the XML is properly formatted... i tried to search and the documentation i found didn't relate to my specific problem.

Comment: i even did the CDATA fix that everyone talks about, and still... # signs everywhere... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i was able to get the text to display properly, was to highlight the entire column in excel, and set the format to Custom -> 0 ... otherwise, in its original format of Text, i only get # signs...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if the XML document was formatted correctly? Because infinite #################### in a cell usually means something is either formatted incorrectly or Excel doesn't understand its type. For example, Excel can't do negative time so subtracting Earlier Date from Later Date = infinite #######. If you hover your mouse over the cell, it may tell you what the issue is.

Comment: See comments on OP... The XML is properly formatted. Just text on separate lines...